# Selenium Java Chrome - Upload File unsupported labels

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, nvidia

Using Selenium Java in Eclipse IDE for Chrome.
Trying to automate a process of uploading images into [Nvidia's Gaugan](http://nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com/gaugan/) and downloading them. Goal is to be able to render out pngs of an animation, and then using this script put them all through the website's renderer.

The problem is, when I try to upload a file via: `element.sendKeys(uploadFile);` and I render it, I get "The segmentation mask may contain unsupported labels." seen [here.](https://gyazo.com/06a1d58b2064f00e36c035b77943ced2)

I can not recreate this by hand. Any ideas?

Here is some relevant code below:

```
//Locate and browse to file
        System.out.println("Uploading: " + uploadFile);
        WebElement browse = driver.findElement(By.id("segmapfile"));
        browse.sendKeys(uploadFile);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        
        //Upload
        WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSegmapLoad"));     
        upload.click();
        System.out.println("Uploaded");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        
        //Convert
        WebElement render = driver.findElement(By.id("render"));
        System.out.println("Clicking Render");
        render.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Rendered");
```

Comment: The message "The segmentation mask may contain unsupported labels." has nothing to do with selenium. Make sure you are able to proceed your scenario manualy.

Answer (score 0):

I know that when I try to use the Gaugan website and draw in it, for whatever reason the "wood" texture/color option seems to never work and gives me the same "The segmentation mask may contain unsupported labels." error, so it could be that one of the colors you're using when uploading from an external source contains that "wood" color? Maybe try uploading some drawings that don't have that yellow/orange color and it might work.

Comment: I second this suggestion. I don't think this is a Selenium webdriver issue.